# libmediainfo: qt5 project undefined symbol errors

Tags: c++, macos, undefined-symbol, qt5.5, mediainfo

I am trying to use libmediainfo with my qt5 project and am getting the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MediaInfoLib::MediaInfo::Open(std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&)", referenced from:
      MainWindow::on_dupeslistWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*) in mainwindow.o
  "MediaInfoLib::MediaInfo::Option(std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&)", referenced from:
      MainWindow::on_dupeslistWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*) in mainwindow.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [VideoTwin.app/Contents/MacOS/VideoTwin] Error 1
19:56:12: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project VideoTwin (kit: default)
When executing step "Make"
```

my .pro file

```
QT       += core gui
QT += sql
QT += concurrent
QT += multimedia multimediawidgets

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_1/include/ $$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX]/src/3rdparty/sqlite
LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_1/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lmediainfo -lzen -lz -lpthread -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_cvv -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_face -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = VideoTwin
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    preferencsedialog.cpp \
    myqlistwidget.cpp \
    $$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX]/src/3rdparty/sqlite/sqlite3.c \
    matchpair.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    preferencsedialog.h \
    myqlistwidget.h \
    matchpair.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    preferencsedialog.ui

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc
```

in my header file

```
#include <MediaInfo/MediaInfo.h>
```

and the relevant section from cpp

```
MediaInfoLib::MediaInfo media_info;
media_info.Option(L"Internet",L"No");
media_info.Open(item->data(Qt::UserRole + FilepathRole).toString().toStdWString());
QString temp = QString::fromWCharArray( media_info.Inform().c_str(),media_info.Inform().length());
ui->video_info->setText(temp);
ui->video_info->show();
```

I'm not sure where the problem is. I have the libmediaplayer.dylib in the /usr/local/lib directory. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linking against the static library and using the "dll" header file did the trick for me:

Put this into your source code

```
#include "MediaInfoDLL/MediaInfoDLL_Static.h"
using namespace MediaInfoDLL;
```

This is the content of the .pro file

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = QtTestMediaInfo
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp

# Adjust this to where you put the source code of MediaInfo
MEDIA_INFO_DIR=~/Downloads/MediaInfo_CLI_GNU_FromSource

#INCLUDEPATH += $${MEDIA_INFO_DIR}/ZenLib/Source
INCLUDEPATH += $${MEDIA_INFO_DIR}/MediaInfoLib/Source
LIBS += -L$${MEDIA_INFO_DIR}/MediaInfoLib/Project/GNU/Library -lmediainfo
LIBS += -L$${MEDIA_INFO_DIR}/ZenLib/Project/GNU/Library -lzen -lz
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are not saying to Qt where is libmediainfo.dylib, so Qt doe not find it.

You need to add it to your .pro file, e.g.:

```
LIBS += $$system(pkg-config --libs libmediainfo)
```

You can have [more examples about how to configure your .pro file in order to link to libmediainfo.dylib](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaConch_SourceCode/blob/06c5fe091ca4b9a9bb1335bc73764c8d64a94dc0/Project/Qt/MediaConch.pro#L180-L197), depending of where is libmediainfo.dylib on your system.

Comment: oops forgot to mention I'm on OS X, also libmediainfo is in /usr/local/lib

Comment: I saw it (".dylib"). The .pro in the example also works for Mac OS X. You can do LIBS += -lmediainfo (e.g. if no pkg-config) but it less portable.

Comment: I'm sorry but you did scroll over right? this thing doesn't wordwrap code

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed the -lmediainfo your .pro. I can not help more :(.